# IIS ReWrite catch .jpg?w=960&h=980

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

I have created IIS Outbound Rules to rewrite to CDN. Example for .mov files

```
<rule name="CDN-01-mov" preCondition="CheckHTML" stopProcessing="true">
<match filterByTags="Img, CustomTags" customTags="src" pattern="http(s)?://www.(example.com)(/public)(/uploads)(.*\.mov)" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="https://cdn.example.com/public/uploads{R:5}" />
</rule>
```

However, I would also like to catch .jpg files. The problem is that the  tags with .jpg files in my application are like this:

files/storage/327/9071615039504vishbjwcgbftdy2my1p6.jpg?w=960&h=980

so it has the ?w=960&h=980 part which I don't know how to catch with regex.

How could I make a regex rule to catch .jpg[anything] ?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

The character before matching .jpg is R1, the character matching .jpg is R2, and the character string after .jpg is R3.

This is Pattern:

```
(.*)(.jpg)(.*)
```

Here is for your reference: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)